# Hibernate DuplicateImportMapping Exception: Mapping two classes to 1 table

Tags: java, hibernate

Have two hbm file named as `version1.hbm.xml` and `version2.hbm.xml`. Included in applicationContext.xml like

```
<property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>version1.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>version2.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
```

version1.hbm.xml starts with:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.entity.v1.domain">
  <class name="Entity1" table="Entity">
```

version2.hbm.xml starts with:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.entity.v2.domain">
  <class name="Entity2" table="Entity">
```

> Using Hibernate 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed by simply adding `auto-import="false"` to hibernate-mapping element. Like this `<hibernate-mapping package="com.package.name" auto-import="false">`